# A strange Exception about notification: ClassCastException: RemoteViews$SetOnClickPendingIntent cannot be cast to RemoteViews$ReflectionAction

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview

I have encounteredd a problem.  I collect a exception message about notification for startForeground. It mainly appears on SamSung GT-I9300, API 15.  Is there any clue about it ?  Expect your fabulous analysis.  Thanks

```
Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.widget.RemoteViews$SetOnClickPendingIntent cannot be cast to 
android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260) 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592) 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```